# Discord Markdown with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

```
message.channel.send({
    embed: {
        color: 0,
        description: `${message.author}made me play a `voice_command`"
```

I'm trying to get `voice_command` to be engraved (like here) but I've forgotten what's needed

I swear it's something like `/*` or `\*` I don't even know. I haven't done it in forever..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
message.channel.send({
    embed: {
        color: 0,
        description: `${message.author} made me play a \`voice_command\``
    }
```

Did it lel.